# AMPScript on Cloud Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl

I've duplicated an older cloud page which works perfectly fine (has 2 pages - the first one asks for a value then the value gets assessed, returns with a 'yes has been found' or 'no has not been found' then is meant to direct them to the second page.

The copied version is not returning any value and it just staying black and not directing them to the second page.

I have only changed the URL and ID for one of the values.

Is there something else I need to look at? Data extensions or something?

I am new to SFMC.

This is the code:

```ampscript
<style>
  input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 28px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #ffc2af;
    background-color: #ffc2af;
    border: 1px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.1s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
    
  input[type="submit"]:hover,
  input[type="submit"]:focus {
    opacity: 0.8;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: 0.1s ease;
  }

  input[type="submit"]:active {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: 0.1s ease;
  }
</style>

<script>%%[
  VAR @flag
  SET @flag = RequestParameter('flag')

  IF @flag != 'true' THEN ]%%
</script>

<div id="saleinfo" align="center"> 
  <form action="https://settlements.geocon.com.au/ASPSaleInfoKeys" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="Settled">
    <input type="hidden" name="project" value="a0p6F00000E4TFXQA3">
    <table align="center" cellspacing="20">
      <input type="hidden" name="saleinfourl" value="https://settlements.geocon.com.au/ASPSaleInfoKeys">
      <input type="hidden" name="salefoundurl" value="https://settlements.geocon.com.au/ASPKeyInfo">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <label for="door">Door Number*:</label><br><br>
          <input id="door" maxlength="40" name="door" size="23" type="text" required="" class="form-input form-input-dark">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--  <tr><td align="center"><label for="tower">Tower:</label><br> <select id="tower" name="tower" class="form-input form-input-dark" style="width: 200px;"><option value="B1">B1</option>
 <option value="B2">B2</option>
     <option value="B3">B3</option>
    </select></td></tr> -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="form-Submit">
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<script>%%[
  ELSE
  IF @salefound == 'Yes' THEN ]%%
</script> 

<form action="https://settlements.geocon.com.au/ASPKeyInfo" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="https://settlements.geocon.com.au/ASPSaleInfoKeys">
  <input type="hidden" name="salefound" value="%%=v(@salefound)=%%">
  <input type="hidden" name="saleid" value="%%=v(@saleid)=%%">
  <input type="hidden" name="saleaccountid" value="%%=v(@saleaccountid)=%%">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="70%" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><br><br>
        <label></label><br><br><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="%%=v(@buttonvalue)=%%" class="form-Submit">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script>%%[  ELSE ]%%</script> 
<form action="https://settlements.geocon.com.au/ASPKeyInfo" method="POST">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="70%" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <br><br><br><br><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p align="center">
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="%%=v(@buttonvalue)=%%" class="form-Submit">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script>%%[  ENDIF ]%%</script>
<script>%%[  ENDIF ]%%</script>
```

Comment: Technically this code seems to be correct..... however one can validate your usecase only with proper understanding of business usecase and possible inputs n respective outcome!... Also its suggested NOT to share Production URLs, IDs etc

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check if the `@flag` variable and `@salefound` variable are being populated. Also use Chrome > View > Developer > Developer Tools to assess if parameters are being posted to those endpoints in the Form POST.

This is less of a CloudPage issue than is it either an AMPscript variable assignment and/or form post.